# Get class name of enum by its value

Tags: c#, .net

I have some enum

```
public enum MyEnum 
{ 
    Field1,
    Field2
}
```

and pass value in function

```
DoSmth(MyEnum.Field1);
```

How can i get classname "MyEnum" in that function

```
void DoSmth(Enum enumArg) 
{
    string className = Magic(enumArg); // className = "MyEnum"
}
```

Comment: it's not a class name.it's the name of your enumeration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the code you've posted doesn't compile. `enum` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name. The following will work, however.

```
void DoSmth(Enum e) 
{
    string className = e.GetType().Name; // className = "MyEnum"
}
```

Comment: ofc doesn't compile, my mistake. It's really simple, sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if `enum` is `MуEnum` then it's better to check as `if (enum is MyEnum)`

If you need type name then you need `enum.GetType().Name`